# Flutter: How to sort data in listview.builder after calculating distance from firebase firestore using latitude and longitude

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, google-maps, geolocation

I am making an app that calculates and shows the nearby businesses by fetching the latitude and longitude which I saved in Firebase Firestore and calculate them according to the user location and i have to put them in listview here and i wanted to sort them according to the nearest location when being calculated and fetched

```
import 'package:e_commerce/zRealDistance/AssistantMethods.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

var passlat;
var passlong;

@override
Future<String> getCurrentLocation(String slatitude, String slongitude) async {
  var slat = double.parse(slatitude);
  var slon = double.parse(slongitude);
  var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
  passlat = position.latitude;
  passlong = position.longitude;

  LatLng a = LatLng(passlat, passlong);
  LatLng b = LatLng(slat, slon);

  var details = await AssistantMethods.obtainDirectionDetails(a, b);

  return details.distanceText;
}
```

Here is the direction detail class

```
class DirectionDetails {
  int distanceValue;
  int durationValue;
  String distanceText;
  String durationText;
  String encodedPoints;
  DirectionDetails({
    this.distanceText,
    this.distanceValue,
    this.durationText,
    this.durationValue,
    this.encodedPoints
  });
}
```

and this below calculates and obtains the direction details

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'request_assistant.dart';
import 'directiondetails.dart';

class AssistantMethods {
  static Future<DirectionDetails> obtainDirectionDetails(
      LatLng initialPosition, LatLng finalPosition) async {
    String directionUrl =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${initialPosition.latitude},${initialPosition.longitude}&destination=${finalPosition.latitude},${finalPosition.longitude}&key=apiKey";

    var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(directionUrl);

    if (res == "failed") {
      print(res.toString());
    }
    if (res == null) {
      print(res.toString());
    }
    try {
      DirectionDetails directionDetails = DirectionDetails();

      directionDetails.encodedPoints =
          res["routes"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];
      directionDetails.distanceText =
          res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["text"];

      directionDetails.distanceValue =
          res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"];

      directionDetails.durationText =
          res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["text"];

      directionDetails.durationValue =
          res["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["duration"]["value"];

      return directionDetails;
    } catch (exp) {
      print(exp.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

and at last this one puts them in a text format in a listtile

```
subtitle: FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getCurrentLocation(
        '${doc[index].data()['latitude']}',
        '${doc[index].data()['longitude']}'),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    List<Widget> children;
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        children = <Widget>[
        Text('Distance: ${snapshot.data}'),
        ];
    } else {
        children = <Widget>[
        JumpingText(
            'Calculating distance...',
        ),
        ];
    }
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment:
            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: children,
    );
    },
),
```

Comment: You're gonna want to seperate your UI from your repository (firebase). Reso coder on youtube has some good tutorials on test driven development and domain driven development that will explain how to do this. Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805917/how-to-sort-list-of-locations-in-flutter-from-firestore